# My custom udev hwdb rule doesn't work

Tags: usb, keyboard, udev

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 installed in EFI Mode, I tried to write simple udev rule which for all external USB keyboards will map <kbd>capslock</kbd> for escape. I use a lot of `vim` and plug and unplug keyboards often so this will simplify things a lot. So following different tutorials I 've made such file

```
cat /etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-keyboard-local.hwdb


keyboard:usb:v*p*
keyboard:usb:v046dpc30e*
    KEYBOARD_KEY_58=esc
```

then I executed

```
udevadm hwdb --update
```

but it doesn't work.
I've used doubled mapping first general rule for any USB keyboard

```
keyboard:usb:v*p*
```

and for the one that I had already plugged

```
keyboard:usb:v046dpc30e*
```

thought maybe specific work will work but unfortunatelly not.

so I tried to debug what is wrong and following other tutorial
run this:

```
udevadm --debug test /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:046D:C30E.0007/input/input20
calling: test
version 204 
This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program
specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

=== trie on-disk === 
tool version:          204 
file size:         5740456 bytes
header size             80 bytes
strings            1262416 bytes
nodes              4477960 bytes
load module index
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-crda.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-gnupg.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-gnupg2.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-hyperv-hotadd.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-inputattach.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libgphoto2-6.rules
GOTO 'libgphoto2_usb_end' has no matching label in: '/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libgphoto2-6.rules'
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb-media-players.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/42-usb-hid-pm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-firmware.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/55-dm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/56-hpmud.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-keyboard.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-pcmcia.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-serial.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/61-accelerometer.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-xorg-xkb.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/66-xorg-synaptics-quirks.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules
IMPORT found builtin 'usb_id --export %p', replacing /lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules:89
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-xorg-vmmouse.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-xserver-xorg-input-wacom.rules
read rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-printers.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-idrac.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-tty-description.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-ericsson-mbm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-huawei-net-port-types.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-longcheer-port-types.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-nokia-port-types.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-pcmcia-device-blacklist.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-platform-serial-whitelist.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-qdl-device-blacklist.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-simtech-port-types.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-usb-device-blacklist.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-usb-serial-adapters-greylist.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-x22x-port-types.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-zte-port-types.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-nm-olpc-mesh.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-graphics-card.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-mm-candidate.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-brltty.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hdparm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hplj10xx.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-keyboard-configuration.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-regulatory.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-usbmuxd.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-alsa-restore.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-alsa-ucm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-libgpod.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-pulseaudio.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-cd-devices.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-udev-late.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-dell.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-fujitsu.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-gateway.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-ibm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-lenovo.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-toshiba.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-csr.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-hid.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-wup.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/97-bluetooth-hid2hci.rules
rules contain 196608 bytes tokens (16384 * 12 bytes), 33727 bytes strings
18818 strings (164973 bytes), 15727 de-duplicated (134338 bytes), 3092 trie nodes used
device 0x15f81b0 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:046D:C30E.0007/input/input20'
device 0x1600050 filled with db file data
device 0x15ff420 has devpath '/devices/virtual/dmi/id'
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'Hewlett-Packard'
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libgphoto2-6.rules:3
device 0x15ff420 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:046D:C30E.0007'
device 0x1605e30 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0'
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0: if_class 3 protocol 0
device 0x1607b80 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2'
device 0x1608170 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3'
device 0x1608550 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0'
device 0x1608930 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00'
IMPORT builtin 'input_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:10
capabilities/ev raw kernel attribute: 120013
capabilities/abs raw kernel attribute: 0
capabilities/rel raw kernel attribute: 0
capabilities/key raw kernel attribute: 1000000000007 ff800000000007ff febeffdff3cfffff fffffffffffffffe
test_key: checking bit block 0 for any keys; found=1
test_key: checking bit block 64 for any keys; found=1
test_key: checking bit block 128 for any keys; found=1
test_key: checking bit block 192 for any keys; found=1
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:11
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' returned non-zero
IMPORT builtin 'path_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules:31
device 0x15ff420 filled with db file data
RUN 'kmod load $env{MODALIAS}' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules:5
unable to create temporary db file '/run/udev/data/+input:input20.tmp': Permission denied
.INPUT_CLASS=kbd
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:046D:C30E.0007/input/input20
EV=120013
ID_BUS=usb
ID_FOR_SEAT=input-pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_2_1_0
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
ID_MODEL=HID_compliant_keyboard
ID_MODEL_ENC=HID\x20compliant\x20keyboard
ID_MODEL_ID=c30e
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_2_1_0
ID_REVISION=0180
ID_SERIAL=Logitech_HID_compliant_keyboard
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030000:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=Logitech
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Logitech
ID_VENDOR_ID=046d
KEY=1000000000007 ff800000000007ff febeffdff3cfffff fffffffffffffffe
LED=7
MODALIAS=input:b0003v046DpC30Ee0110-e0,1,4,11,14,k71,72,73,74,75,77,79,7A,7B,7C,7D,7E,7F,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,8A,B7,B8,B9,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,C0,C1,C2,F0,ram4,l0,1,2,sfw
MSC=10
NAME="Logitech HID compliant keyboard"
PHYS="usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0"
PRODUCT=3/46d/c30e/110
PROP=0
SUBSYSTEM=input
TAGS=:seat:
UDEV_LOG=7
UNIQ=""
USEC_INITIALIZED=3550400
run: 'kmod load input:b0003v046DpC30Ee0110-e0,1,4,11,14,k71,72,73,74,75,77,79,7A,7B,7C,7D,7E,7F,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,8A,B7,B8,B9,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,C0,C1,C2,F0,ram4,l0,1,2,sfw'
unload module index
```

Any idea how can I debug it and make it work?

Answer (score 6):

The format is `KEYBOARD_KEY_<hex scan code>`. Use 'evtest' to find the correct scan code. Run it, select the appropriate device and press the key you want the scan code for.
Look for something like:

```
Event: time 1410505361.975680, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70039
Event: time 1410505361.975680, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 58 (KEY_CAPSLOCK), value 1
```

You want the code located after `MSC_SCAN`, so on my keyboard it is 70039, I believe this is true for all USB-keyboards.

Also, after:

```
udevadm hwdb --update
```

you need:

```
udevadm trigger
```

To activate the new mapping.

Comment: It is true for my USB keyboard too. I had to reboot(!) to activate the new mapping though.

Comment: Did you run the two udevadm commands I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. For me the problem is actually here:

```
kmod load $env{MODALIAS}' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules:5
```

I suspect that what you want is some other rule, but what you are getting is this:

```
kmod load input:b0003v046DpC30Ee0110-e0,1,4,11,14,k71,72,73,74,75,77,79,7A,7B,7C,7D,7E,7F,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,8A,B7,B8,B9,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,C0,C1,C2,F0,ram4,l0,1,2,sfw
```

Try adding back:

```
DRIVER!="?*", ENV{MODALIAS}=="?*", RUN{builtin}="kmod load $env{MODALIAS}"
```

To line 5 of `80-drivers.rules` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a pattern that actually matches the hwdb lookups that the udev rules actually in your system are doing, keeping in mind that the distro's udev rules may be different in newer versions.

You need to know how to figure out what the pattern needs to look like from the information that the `udevadm test` is directing you to.

The relevant `/dev/input/by-id/*-kbd` device for me is `/dev/input/by-id/usb-GASIA_PS2toUSB_Adapter-event-kbd`.

Doing `udevadm` `test` on it:

```
$ sudo udevadm --debug test `udevadm info -q path -n /dev/input/by-id/usb-GASIA_PS2toUSB_Adapter-event-kbd`
```

You need to look for the lines where there is evidence of relevant hwdb lookups being done by udev rules:

```
...
event14: IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules:8
...
event14: IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules:17
...
```

If you have a look at the referenced rules files, you can see what rules there are that were hit, and then figure out the ones that are selective enough to match the device you want to do remapping on. For instance, at my `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules` line 17:

```
# device matching the input device name + properties + the machine's DMI data
KERNELS=="input*", IMPORT{builtin}="hwdb 'evdev:name:$attr{name}:phys:$attr{phys}:ev:$attr{capabilities/ev}:$attr{[dmi/id]modalias}'", \
  RUN{builtin}+="keyboard", GOTO="evdev_end"
```

So the string being looked up in hwdb starts with `evdev:name:` followed by the name attribute of the device, but what is that?

Use `udevadm info -a` on the device to see its attributes (in addition to using information about more dynamic substitutions that you already may have in the `udevadm test` log):

```
$ udevadm info -a -n /dev/input/by-id/usb-GASIA_PS2toUSB_Adapter-event-kbd
...
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.0/0003:0E8F:0020.0002/input/input19':
    ...
    ATTRS{name}=="GASIA PS2toUSB Adapter"
    ...
```

So the name is `GASIA PS2toUSB Adapter`, and my pattern can be

```
evdev:name:GASIA PS2toUSB Adapter:*
```

This seems selective enough for my purposes to just match the device I want to remap keys on.

Now it's just a matter of using `evtest` on the device to get the USB scan codes to map, and looking in `/usr/src/linux/input-event-codes.h` to figure out the keysyms to map them to, and putting it all together into the custom hwdb file.

`/etc/udev/hwdb.d/90-custom-keyboard.hwdb`:

```
evdev:name:GASIA PS2toUSB Adapter:*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70056=backspace
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7003c=kpminus
 # ...
```

then

```
sudo systemd-hwdb update
sudo udevadm trigger
```