# udev doesn't load rule automatically after reboot

Tags: server, 18.04, dell, udev

I have a rule that should apply to `/dev/ipmi0` to change its group and mode. When I reboot, that node shows as root:root, but if I run "test" it successfully applies it:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-ipmi-nonroot.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="ipmi", KERNEL=="ipmi0", GROUP="adm", MODE="0660"

$ ls -l /dev/ipmi*
crw------- 1 root root 244, 0 Jul  6 16:57 /dev/ipmi0

$ sudo udevadm test /sys/class/ipmi/ipmi0
....
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/97-dmraid.rules
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-ipmi-nonroot.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules
rules contain 49152 bytes tokens (4096 * 12 bytes), 14763 bytes strings
2054 strings (26612 bytes), 1334 de-duplicated (12570 bytes), 721 trie nodes used
GROUP 4 /etc/udev/rules.d/99-ipmi-nonroot.rules:1
MODE 0660 /etc/udev/rules.d/99-ipmi-nonroot.rules:1
handling device node '/dev/ipmi0', devnum=c244:0, mode=0660, uid=0, gid=4
preserve permissions /dev/ipmi0, 020660, uid=0, gid=4
preserve already existing symlink '/dev/char/244:0' to '../ipmi0'
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/ipmi0
...

$ ls -l /dev/ipmi*
crw-rw---- 1 root adm 244, 0 Jul  6 17:00 /dev/ipmi0
```

I also tried `udev trigger` [as seen in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/523104/69983). It will also change the group to `adm`, but doesn't "stick" after a reboot either. Should I be placing my rule under `/lib` instead of `/etc`? That feels wrong.

Comment: Did you update the initramfs? It might be that the ipmi driver is loaded in the ramdisk, but the rule is missing. `update-initramfs -u -k all`

Comment: Could you check the output of `journalctl -b0 | grep -F '/etc/udev/rules.d/99-ipmi-nonroot.rules'` ?

Comment: See [my question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1373624/21005)